# Finding minterms of a 5-var Boolean Expression having 10 terms containing NAND

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have this question for my assignment and I am not getting that how can we find the minterms of this expression. It has 10 terms, it is 5 variable expression and it contains NAND.

**Expression:**

$F=AB'E+(BC)'DE'+(CD)'E+A'DE'+A'CDE'+A(CD)'E+AE+A(BE)'+(AC)'+BCD'$

I tried the following approach:

**My Approach:**

1. Eliminating NAND from the expression using Laws and Properties
2. Modifying each term to have every input/variable
3. Removing the duplicate terms using Identity Law

But this result in giving 32 minterms from 0 - 32 that is SIGMA(m0, m2, m3, m4.....m32) and if we look the expression has 5 variables and `2^n = 2^5 = 32` shows the Karnaugh Map will have 32 Cells. Therefore, if we get 32 minterms, all of the Karnaugh Map's Cells are gonna filled up and that is totally confusing me.

Kindly tell me how should I find the minterms so that I can map them on K-Map as required in my Assignment Question. The actual Question's pic is below:

[image]

Comment: The "NAND"s might be just mis-printed combinations of two adjacent inverted literals.

Comment: @AxelKemper thank you so much, so should I consider these two separate literals? For instance, should I consider $(BC)'$ as $B'C'$? If yes, then should I do the same process I explained in 'My Approach' section except the first point of removing `NANDs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) should look similar to this one:

[image]

There is a [nice application online](http://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/~thormae/lectures/ti1/code/karnaughmap/) for your own experiments.

Here is an alternative form in typewriter style (without encircled blocks):

```
            de                     de
      00  01  11  10         00  01  11  10
 abc +---+---+---+---+  abc +---+---+---+---+
 000 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  001 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
     +---+---+---+---+      +---+---+---+---+
 010 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |  011 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
     +---+---+---+---+      +---+---+---+---+
 110 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |  111 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
     +---+---+---+---+      +---+---+---+---+
 100 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  101 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
     +---+---+---+---+      +---+---+---+---+
```

The simplified expression:

> ae + a!b + !a!c + bc!d + !ad!e

Comment: @AlexKemper thank you so much man, you saved a my time a lot. Before seeing your this reply I have already extracted the minterms by considering those adjacent interval literals as separated interval literals. I got 25 minterms as you have mention above in K-Map. I also almost made the K-Map, but what I wanted to know is that how did you group those 1's? I mean is there any specific Rule or Law or any technique? Actually I am new to this topic and still reading about it in my book. But I have not understood that how do we group the 1's in K-Map. Kindly if you can explain it to me step by step?

Comment: Minterm groups must be four-sided rectangular and must have an area that is a power of two (i.e., 1, 2, 4, 8…). Minterm rectangles should be as large as possible without containing any 0s. Groups may overlap in order to make each one larger.

Comment: I see, then why in the K-Map you have shown, the little green rectangle in the mid not over-lapping the brown one? Also, why the brown rectangle not over-lapping the green towards left?

Comment: Also, please may I know that what tool did you use to create K-Map whose pic you posted here in the answer? :)

Comment: Minterm groups may consist of two or four blocks located at opposite edges or corners. To get this idea, mark the cells for `!AD!E`. The diagram was created by a home-grown tool which I implemented inspired by the web application I linked in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining everything and give me some of your time. I would like to know that did you make this tool using a Programming Language? If yes then which Language did you use? is it available for sale or anything like that? I would like to buy it some day.

Comment: I am using a set of home-grown tools, written in `C#`. One tool translates Boolean expressions to truth-tables and calls the open source `PLA` minimizer `Espresso` to minimize the truth-table. A second tool takes the minimized table to create the `Karnaugh` map. Sorry, but I don't have the time to publish these tools and support them. Have a look at the freeware tool [Logic Friday](https://sontrak.com/). That might suit your needs.

Comment: Oh, that's fine then. Well, I need to ask one more thing. If we change the order of putting `variables` on `K-Map`, like for example if I put $A$ and $B$ on the left side and $C$, $D$ and $E$ on the top, then would it make any effect on the simplified expression? I meant would it change the simplified expression which you have written below? Or the expression will be same regardless of the placings of `variables` on `K-Map`?

Comment: Also I would like to correct a mistake (it might be a typo from you). In simplified expression which you wrote at the end of your answer, the term $BC'D$ should be $BCD'$. Check it again and tell me if I am wrong, thanks. :)

Comment: `bc!d` is equivalent to `bcd'` in your notation. The questionmark as `not operator` is put before (to the left of) the variable while the apostrophe is put behind (to the right). The ordering of variables in the Karnaugh map is just a matter of cosmetics. As long as the rows and columns are clearly designated, the expression can always be derived from the map and vice versa.

Comment: Oh yes, got it. Sorry, I did not look at it deeply. Thanks by the way. Loved this conversation. I hope to have a discussion with you again on any topic if I find it difficult. I have added you in my list in Xing.com as well so that we can have the discussion, if required.